# ModRewrite ReWriteCond Remote_Host lead string subsection boolean

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I express a lead subsection with the rest being boolean in a ReWriteCond?

example: *google-proxy-12-345-67-890.google.com*

I want to target **google-proxy**-12-345-67-890.google.com so that all **google-proxy**-(boolean) connections are denied.

using something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} google-proxy*\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: any and everything after google-proxy-

Comment: Yes, sure... 

**google-proxy**-12-345-67-890.google.com 
**google-proxy**-66-234-126-12.google.com 
**google-proxy**-12-server-123-abc.google.com 

anything that starts with **google-proxy**

Comment: ok what's the error with your rule?

Comment: using **google-proxy*\.** is blocking all access. The * is blocking all ip traffic in that configuration. Also I do not wish to block in the reverse order, example: **.\.google\.com** as I only wish to block the google-proxy ips, and the google-proxy is always a different ip, so if I can specify just **google-proxy** in some way, it would accomplish my need. I tried to do something like: **google-proxy-[+]\.** but it also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex needs little bit of tweaking. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^google-proxy- [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```